# What is the pronunciation of vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a standard pronunciation?

Some tells me to read V-I-M, but someone tellls me to read /vim/.

The right way is  V-I-M or /vim/?

Answer (score 29):

This can be read in the help at `:h pronounce`

> Vim is pronounced as one word, like Jim, not vi-ai-em.  It's written
> with a capital, since it's a name, again like Jim.

Comment: E149: Sorry, no help for pronounce on my gVim

Comment: I am wondering why, since you link to the exact same paragraph. You should probably update your vim runtime documentation. Helptag is there: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/intro.txt#L46

Answer (score 12):

From [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html)...

"Vim is pronounced as one word, like Jim, not vi-ai-em.  It's written with a capital, since it's a name, again like Jim"